# Plotly express Choropleth side by side with different colors

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, choropleth

I am trying to plot 2 choropleth maps side by side with two different columns: temperature (in degrees) and discount (in percentage). Here are the codes I am using

```
fig_1 = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, locations = 'code', geojson=municipalities_json, color = 'discount')
fig_1.update_geos(fitbounds = 'locations', visible = False)

fig_2 = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, locations = 'code', geojson=municipalities_json, color = 'est_ma_hightemp')
fig_2.update_geos(fitbounds = 'locations', visible = False)

  

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    subplot_titles=['Discounts', 'Weather'],
                    specs=[[{'type': 'choroplethmapbox'}, {'type': 'choroplethmapbox'}]])

fig.add_trace(fig_1['data'][0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig_2['data'][0], row=1, col=2)

fig.update_mapboxes(style='white-bg',
                    center={'lat': 37.3, 'lon': 127.6751},
                    zoom=5.8)

fig.update_layout(title_text='Title',
                  margin={'l': 0, 'r': 0, 't': 100, 'b': 0},
                  height=1000)

fig.show()
```

The figure has one color bar only. Obviously, this does not make any sense. Is there a way to use two different color bars?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have data for graphs or geojson data, so I don't know if it can be done with express. It is possible to achieve this using a graph object. This code is modified from the [example answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/synchronize-zoom-pan-for-two-mapbox-plots/40673) in the plotly community to fit your code. Another thing to realize is that you need a free access token for the mapbox. The graph data and geojson data are from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/#indexing-by-geojson-properties).

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapboxtoken = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

df = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['Discounts', 'Weather'],
    specs=[[{"type": "mapbox"}, {"type": "mapbox"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=geojson, 
                                  locations=df['district'], 
                                  z=df['Coderre'],
                                  featureidkey='properties.district',
                                  colorscale='Viridis',
                                  colorbar=dict(thickness=20, x=0.46),
                                  marker=dict(opacity=0.75)), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=geojson, 
                                  locations=df['district'], 
                                  z=df['Bergeron'],
                                  featureidkey='properties.district',
                                  colorscale='matter_r',
                                  colorbar=dict(thickness=20, x=1.02),
                                  marker=dict(opacity=0.75, line_width=0.5)), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_mapboxes(
        bearing=0,
        accesstoken=mapboxtoken,
        center = {"lat": 45.5517 , "lon": -73.7073 },
 )
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=50, b=10))

fig.update_layout(mapbox1=dict(zoom=8.5, style='carto-positron'),
                  mapbox2=dict(zoom=8.5, style='light'))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. I have a follow-up question. Is there a way to show only the shaded areas? I added the following code "fig.update_geos(fitbounds = 'locations', visible = False)", but it does not work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've done some research and it seems that there is no function in the map box to negate the map box.